# Non-scalar type Sub-class error

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I must be living in a bizarro version of C++. In a section of my code I have:

```
TemplateIterator<sf::Sound> Temp;
TemplateIteratorNonConst<sf::Sound> Temp2 = Temp;
```

Ignore the 'constness' naming conventions as TemplateIteratorNonConst is not presently any different from TemplateIterator. I get the error:

```
'TL::TemplateIterator<sf::Sound>' to non-scalar type 'TL::TemplateIteratorNonConst<sf::Sound>' requested
```

Which implies that C++ is having conversion issues. The mind-boggling fact is, TemplateIteratorNonConst is an empty sub-derivative, *an exact duplicate of TemplateIterator[1]*:

```
//Empty to demonstrate the absurdity of the error
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TemplateIteratorNonConst : public TemplateIterator<TemplateItem>
{
private:
protected:
public:
};
```

Even if I define the assignment operator (no matter which kind - TemplateIterator to NonConsts, vice versa, same for same etc), it makes no difference, it spits out the same error. It wouldn't be such a confusing error if it wasn't for the fact that:

```
TemplateIterator<sf::Sound> Temp;
TemplateList<sf::Sound> Temp2 = Temp; //A sub-class of TemplateIterator
```

Produces absolutely no errors. Why is it, TemplateList, a sub-class of TemplateIterator, gets no 'non-scalar type' warnings in the exact same scenario, but TemplateIteratorNonConst, also a sub-class (and exact dupe) of TemplateIterator, does?

I can't give a full code example due to length of both TemplateIterator and TemplateList on this page, and I've been unable to replicate the error with simple classes (exact duplicate sub-classes give no errors when performing assignment either way).

Why is this error occuring, and **without static type-casting** (given TemplateList requires no type-casting to work and TemplateIteratorNonConst is a self-explanatory duplicate of TemplateIterator so it should not be necessary) how do I fix the problem?

(I feel static type-casting is covering up a more major problem on the underneath so I'd much rather address it).

[1]Okay, maybe not an 'exact' duplicate (it is a subclass of TemplatorIterator) for pedants but you know what I mean.

Comment: You're confused about sub and super. A cat is an animal, but an animal is not necessarily a cat. Also look up "slicing".

Comment: Both TemplateList and TemplateIteratorNonConst are sub-classes (sub-classes of TemplateIterator). I haven't called TemplateIterator a subclass so I am not sure what you're confused about? Slicing shouldn't occur because the assignment operators will handle that (for the record, they all contain the exact same datatypes but C++ only throws an error on TemplateIteratorNonConst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A super type isn't convertible implicitly to one of each subtype. So I'm not surprised that it doesn't work for TemplateIteratorNonConst. If it works for TemplateList, the most probable cause is that TemplateList has a constructor taking a TemplateIterator.

Note that in

```
TemplateList<sf::Sound> Temp2 = Temp;
```

no assignment operator is used, it tries to use a constructor just as with

```
TemplateList<sf::Sound> Temp2(Temp);
```

with the additional requirement that the constructor can't be implicit.

To solve your problem, you have to either

- provides a `TemplateIteratorNonConst(TemplateIterator<TemplateItem> const&);` in TemplateIteratorNonConst
- provides a `operator TemplateIteratorNonConst<TemplateItem>();` in TemplateIterator.

The first option is probably the best if you control both.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. I decided that if TemplateList works, I could copy TemplateList and remove what I don't need from it to see what it has the other doesn't. Which is a copy constructor.

Comment: @user1433767, `D::D(T const&)` where D != T and variants aren't copy constructors. They are one parameter constructor which are used implicitly to convert T to D when needed if they are not also `explicit`. The fact that T is a base class of D or not doesn't change that.

Comment: Oh okay, misuse/misunderstanding of terminology on my behalf. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a

```
TemplateIteratorNonConst::TemplateIteratorNonConst(const TemplateIterator<T>& other)
```

constructor and one

```
TemplateIteratorNonConst::operator=(const TemplateIterator<T>& other)
```

overload in your `TemplateIteratorNonConst` that takes `TemplateIterator<T>`